# JBoss does not start because Address localhost:1099 is already in use

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jboss

**Environment:**

- JBoss 6
- IntelliJ IDEA 14.14
- Java 6
- Javaee 6
- Windows 7 x64

I'm not capable of staring my JBoss server, because it complains because the port 1099 is already in use.

**ERROR**

```
Error running des: Address localhost:1099 is already in use
```

I've done a nmap to this port an this is the result

```
PORT     STATE   SERVICE     VERSION
1099/tcp unknown rmiregistry
```

But I don't have a clue which process, it could be.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a netstat command to find out, which process is it

```
netstat -a -b -o
```

-a flag is to display all connection and ports

-b is to get executable

-o is to get PID

And then you can try to kill this process, or if it has to be alive, you can reconfigure your JBoss server to bind a JNDI service to port other then 1099

Or just kill all java processes with the following command:

```
taskkill /f -im java.exe
```

Comment: After a while, the computer free the port and then I could restart de server. could it be any update process?

Comment: Not sure, as for me, in most cases it happened because of some IDE plugins or if previously runned JBoss instance was not properly stopped

Answer (score 3):

port 1099 is being used by another service. change the port in standalone(-full).xml to some available port. (i.e., 8080).

Answer (score 0):

just kill all the processes `java.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to avoid getting `Address localhost:1099 is already in use` error.

**First way:**

Goto **Task Manager** and select **Processes** tab.

Find the process named `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` and this represents `java.exe`

Select this **process** and **kill** it.

Now you are good to go with the JBOSS server. Start it.

**Second way:**

Go to **bin** **folder** in the `JBoss` location

E.g. (In my PC)

```
D:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin
```

Press **Shift** key in the keyboard and **right click**

Select Open Command Window Here

Then type, `shutdown.bat -S` and enter

It will take some to down the server and then you are good to go.